# How Can I Make A Public API Route For An AWS Lambda Function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Does AWS Lambda provide a way to make a public route/endpoint for my Lambda functions?

Or do I have to build an entire app to handle routing and invoking Lambda functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they do!

As of July 9th they have an api endpoint section that allows you to invoke your lambda function from anywhere!

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/07/invoke-aws-lambda-functions-over-https/.

You can also use API gateway with lambda to design and test your api.